# UITapGestureRecognizer in UIScrollView subview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use a single tap recognizer in an imageView (that is also a scrollView child).
In Interface Builder I've created and referentiated the scrollView only.
Works the scrolling but the single tap event is not recognized (nothing is logged). 
Here's the code:

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

[myImage release];

// add gesture recognizers to the image view
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

[singleTap release];

[imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];

[imageScrollView addSubview:imageView]; }

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// single tap handling
NSLog(@"sinlgeTap called"); }
```

I've looked around for hours and tried many things. Maybe a look of someone else can help much more.
Thanks.

Comment: enabling the userInteraction for imageView, will fire singleTap... but scrolling won't work any more.

Comment: Is there any way to have scrolling functionality and a gesture recognizer working together?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've enabled the userInteraction for imageView and also the canCancelContentTouches option for the scrollView:

```
[imageScrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

It works now.

Comment: why do you have to to [imageScrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES]? Also in you case you have one image, what if there are multiple image, what code do you have in handleSingleTap to figure out on which image the tap event occured

Comment: the UIGestureRecognizer has view as a property. So you can just do something like UIImageView* thisView = UIGestureRecognizer.view, you could probably also cast UIImageView, not sure if that would be necessary UIImageView* thisView = (UIImageView*) UIGestureRecognizer.view

Comment: Yeah per @Yogesh, you only really need to use [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES] for this to work.